# How to override context.getUser()

Tags: xpages

for a my current project I would like to overide the context.getUser() method to return a custom pojo which extends the default object returned?

The reason I would like to do is so that I dont have to use the sessionScope technique of saving person specific data and just can call context.getUser() instead (which checks which user is logged on (or anonymous) and retrieves all data needed without.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not override context.getUser() - you don't know what else that may require. Have you looked at the userBean and or peopleBean from the extension library? You could use that to get any information you need, then if you need more, or want to create a custom class that extends those beans, install it as a scoped bean in your application, and then use it as the base for your own getUser().